# Can't do nothing in Oracle Apex if workspace is not internal

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have installed Oracle Apex 5.1.3 and fresh OracleDb12.

Now I can login in `internal` workspace and create other workspaces, but if I login with `Admin` account into enother workspace and go to `SQL workshop` or try to install any sample application I have en error

> User ADMIN has no privileges on the schema.

I try to grant all privileges to ANONYMOUS role, but it wasn't help.
What I am doing wrong? Should I configure users or roles in database?

Comment: Is that all the error message you get? i.e. no ORA code?

Comment: There is no ORA code, only message about privileges. Apex was installed in CDB, could it be possible cause?

Comment: Not sure. I would try associating the schema with the workspace, perhaps for some reason it wasn't done initially. To do this: `sqlplus /nolog` `connect sys as sysdba` `alter session set current_schema=apex_050100;` `exec apex_instance_admin.add_schema('WORKSPACE','USER');`

Comment: p.s. I believe the current best advice is to install APEX into the PDB rather than the CDB.